# Pronunciation of patchim in 맛있다 and 맛없다

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-korean

I am wondering how Korean pronounce the patchim ㅅ in 맛 of the adjectives below.

> 1. 맛있다
> 2. 맛없다

When read words (맛, 있, 다) separately the ㅅ in 맛 sounds like ㄷ. However, because the word after 맛 (있 and 없) starts with a vowel so we tend to connect the patchim with the vowel. In this case, I am not sure how would you pronounce the patchim, ㄷ or ㅅ?

> 1. 맛있다 is read as 마 딨 다 or 마 싰 다
> 2. 맛없다 is read as 마 덦 다 or 마 섮 다

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 맛있다 is read as 마싣따, as if it were one "phonological word"
2. 맛없다 is read as 마덥따, as if it were 맛 and 없다 as two phonological words See [here](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=12853400).

You can find recordings here in [this TTMIK Lesson](http://talktomeinkorean.com/lessons/l1l12/).

Comment: 마딛따 is also a correct pronunciation of 맛있다 although I hardly hear 마싣따 in real life. My father, a former high school Korean teacher, is pretty much the only person who pronounces it as 마딛따 in everyday life. But it is a valid pronunciation.

Comment: According to [표준어 규정 제2부 제4장 제15항](http://kornorms.korean.go.kr/regltn/regltnView.do?regltn_code=0002#a408), there are the two correct ways to pronounce 맛있다: 마딛따 and 마싣따.