# 받침 and following 이응

Tags: pronunciation, final-consonant

Until recently, I was under the impression that if a syllable ended in a 받침 (e.g. 작) and the next syllable started with 이응 (e.g. 아), then the 받침 would move to the start of the next syllable (so 작아 is pronounced like 자가).

But 맛없다 is pronounced like 마덥따, not like 마섭따 as the above rule would predict.

Anyone have a good explanation for this? What are some other examples of this phenomenon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pronunciation of patchim in 맛있다 and 맛없다](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/pronunciation-of-patchim-in-%eb%a7%9b%ec%9e%88%eb%8b%a4-and-%eb%a7%9b%ec%97%86%eb%8b%a4)

Comment: You should look up 맛없다 [here](http://kornorms.korean.go.kr/regltn/regltnView.do?regltn_code=0002&regltn_no=346#a346). The rule says "받침 뒤에 모음 ‘ㅏ, ㅓ, ㅗ, ㅜ, ㅟ’ 들로 시작되는 실질 형태소가 연결되는 경우에는, 대표음으로 바꾸어서 뒤 음절 첫소리로 옮겨 발음한다."

Answer (score 1):

Korean only have a few possible sounds at the end of a syllable such as ㄱ,ㄷ,ㅂ,ㄴ,ㅁ,ㅇ,ㄹ, so other consonants' pronunciations should be changed.

ㄱ ㅋ ㄲ -> ㄱ

ㄷ ㅌ **ㅅ** ㅆ ㅈ ㅊ ㅎ-> **ㄷ**

ㅂ ㅍ -> ㅂ

ㄴ -> ㄴ

ㅁ -> ㅁ

ㅇ -> ㅇ

ㄹ -> ㄹ

When two consonants appear in the final position, only one of them is pronounced

ㄳ ㄺ -> ㄱ

ㄵ ㄶ -> ㄴ

ㄼ ㄽ ㄾ ㅀ -> ㄹ

ㄻ -> ㅁ

ㄿ **ㅄ** -> **ㅂ**

Final consonants move to the start of the next syllable when followed by a vowel, except ㅇ and ㅎ. ㅇ does not move, and ㅎ disappears before a vowel.

웃음 [우슴]

영어 [영어]

국어 [구거]

맛없다 [맏업따] -> [마덥따] 
According to the first rule, 받침 ㅅ change into ㄷ and then 받침 ㄷ moves to the next vowel. And in 없, 받침 ㅄ is pronounced as ㅂ so it becomes [업]